# it is possible to raise external event inside foreach loop?

Tags: c#, revit-api

I am trying to update parameters in external event and display the update
in revit type parameters

[image]

Is there any method to perform this operation

Thanks in advance ..

Comment: please refer the image also

Comment: Post your code as code using markdown, please. Don't post t as image.

Comment: Don't post an image containing code, remove the image and post the code in markdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can raise an external event in a loop.
But Revit will decide when to call the external event handler. And it must be some while after your LOOP has finished.
Suppose you loop 100 times, which means you raise external events (they can be the same event, or totally different events) 100 times. Then you loop finishes, then all the rest codes after the loop finishes, anyway your codes will finish. After the program main control is returned back to Revit, Revit will quickly decide to sequentially call all the 100 event handlers, right the same sequence you raised them.
Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is very possible, but if your changing variables on every loop then your IExternalEventHandler must be ICloneable and called in a special method like this:

```
aPublicAsyncMethod(ExternalEvent.Create(((_934_PRLoogle_Command06_EE15_CreateNewTags)myWindow2.my__934_PRLoogle_Command06_EE15_CreateNewTags.Clone())));


public async void aPublicAsyncMethod(ExternalEvent myExternalEvent)
        {
            myExternalEvent.Raise();

            while (myExternalEvent.IsPending)
            {
                await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(200); 
            }
        }
```